# How can I apply the same exceptions to multiple functions without copying the code?

Tags: python

I have two different functions that catch the same exceptions, for example:

```
def func1():
    try:
        # ...do something
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
    except NotADirectoryError as e:
        print(e)

def func2():
    try:
        # ...do something else
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
    except NotADirectoryError as e:
        print(e)
```

How can I avoid doing writing these identical exceptions for each function?

My ideal scenario would be to have it like this:

```
def func1():
    # ... do something while catching those exceptions without explicitly stating them here.

def func2():
    # ... do something while catching those exceptions without explicitly stating them here.
```

Comment: An option is not to catch these exceptions within these functions and capture them in the outer code that uses them @tera_789

Comment: It seems like you want [`suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) but with printing, so maybe look at how you could modify [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/contextlib.py#L342) of that.

Comment: @Todd this turned out to be the best option

Comment: @tera_789 you mean catching the exceptions outside these functions?

Comment: @Todd yes exactly

Comment: @tera_789 cool, I'm glad you found a good resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of decorators, but generally speaking it is a bad practice to handle exceptions inside function or class methods, exceptions should be raised in function/methods and should be handled in outer scope.

Nevertheless the code is as follows:

```py
# create decorator function it can be used in any class, with any function or method:
def my_decorator(f):
    def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        except TypeError as e:
            print(e)
    return decorated_func


# some class with some static methods:
class MyClass:
    @my_decorator
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if x == 5:
            raise TypeError("C")
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print(self.x/self.y)

    @staticmethod
    @my_decorator
    def test(a, b, c):
        if a == 1:
            raise ValueError("A")
        print(a + b + c)

    @staticmethod
    @my_decorator
    def test_two(a, b):
        if b == 1:
            raise TypeError("B")
        print(a * b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass.test(a=2, b=2, c=3)
    MyClass.test(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    MyClass.test_two(a=1, b=1)
    MyClass.test_two(a=2, b=2)

    z = MyClass(1, 1)
    z2 = MyClass(5, 5)
```

Actually the correct way to handle errors should be the following, all exceptions are handled in "client" code, not in scope of methods and functions. It is the best way to handle exception if you are going to use your library in some other apps:

```
def some_f(x, y):
    if x == 1:
        raise Exception("x = 1 it is bad")
    print(x + y)


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def sum_them(self):
        if self.x == 1:
            raise Exception("Incorrect x")
        print(self.x + self.y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # so called "client" code
    try:
        some_f(1, 3)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    try:
        z = SomeClass(1, 2)
        z.sum_them()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Comment: Thanks; what exactly do you mean by outer scope?

Comment: @tera_789 outer scope in the case of standalone function means that you do not handle exception inside the function itself, in the case of class method, you should not handle exceptions inside method istelf. I'll add code example to answer soon.

Comment: @tera_789 added example how exceptions should be handled to the answer. I've previously read about it in another forum toster.ru (it is russian speaking forum), and from my working experience I can say that it is TRUE.

Comment: Yep, handling exceptions in the outer scope proved to be my best option; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a decorator.

```
from functools import wraps


def just_report_file_errors(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(e)
        except NotADirectoryError as e:
            print(e)

    return decorator


@just_report_file_errors
def func1():
    pass  # do thing...


@just_report_file_errors
def func2():
    pass  # do thing...
```

Comment: Why the import of `wraps` with the `@wraps`? That's not really needed, right?

Comment: Thanks; I'll try it out and update back. By the way, those methods are defined inside the class. Does it change anything? Would I also define this decorator inside the class?

Comment: @ChatterOne It need for preventing overwriting `__doc__` or `__name__` of `fn`. See https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @tera_789 Yes you can define decorate inside the class. Note that instance methods need `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: @tera_789 You should be able to decorate a method with this just fine; `*args, **kwargs` will pass `self` through.

Comment: @ChatterOne if you want to have the correct name of fuction which was decoreated in error log, you should better use ```@wraps``` otherwise ```f.__name__``` will give you incorrect results, you'll get decotor function name instead.